# Can a user see the JWT when making the http request?

Tags: http, request, jwt

I'm making http request from React to our API for authentication. I'm using `fetch` to make the requests.

My question is, can a user go to the network tab in chrome dev tools, find the request, and see their own token?

Answer (score 1):

It depends.

Normally, user can see all request headers in the HTTP request, in Network panel of Chrome dev tool.

However, after Chrome 67, a new feature named "[Site isolation](https://www.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/site-isolation)" was introduced, and enabled by default. As a result:

> In Chrome's DevTools, cookies and other request headers are not shown in the network panel for cross-site subresource requests.

That is, if JWT token is transferred by cookie in a subdomain site, and the domain of JWT-cookie is wildcard, it will not be displayed in Network panel.

Here is an example. cookie `token`'s domain is `.miaotest.com`, and it is used in HTTP request to site `cshao.miaotest.com`. While this cookie is transferred to backend successfully, you won't see it in "Request Headers" part in dev tool.

Cookie `token`'s information in "Application" panel:
[image]

Cookie `token` is sent but not displayed in Network panel:
[image]

Please note the "Site isolation" feature can be disabled by visiting [chrome://flags/#site-isolation-trial-opt-out](http://chrome://flags/#site-isolation-trial-opt-out) in Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, he can see the whole request including all request headers.